# Why is my label not perfectly cornered at the bottom left of the screen?

Tags: libgdx

Create a normal .fnt file with Hiero. Arial, size 22, no padding...

[image]

---

Make a Label, put it at the bottom left of the screen...

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("MyFont.fnt"));
Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle(font, new Color(1,1,1,1));
label = new Label("Hello", style);
label.setX(0);
label.setY(0);
```

---

You get this:

[image]

---

Take a closer look...

[image]

---

Observe how there is a small space on the left and the bottom. I was expecting the label to be perfectly cornered, but it is not.

It is not clear to me ***why*** is this happening. This is the .fnt data:

```
info face="ArialMT" size=22 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=0,0
common lineHeight=26 base=20 scaleW=256 scaleH=128 pages=1 packed=0
page id=0 file="MyFont.png"
chars count=94
char id=32   x=0     y=0     width=0     height=0     xoffset=0     yoffset=20    xadvance=6     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=64   x=0     y=0     width=22     height=23     xoffset=1     yoffset=3    xadvance=22     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=124   x=22     y=0     width=3     height=23     xoffset=2     yoffset=3    xadvance=6     page=0  chnl=0 
........
```

So my question is: why is my label not perfectly cornered at the bottom left of the screen?

libGDX 0.9.9.

Comment: Are you by any chance using "ExtendViewport"? It's the only thing that comes to my mind.